# How do I stop my iPhone from being automounted?

Tags: mount, vmware, iphone

I'm trying to stop my Ubuntu desktop from automatically mounting my iPhone when I connect it/plug it in. This causes my Vmware workstation to *not* mount the iphone for syncing.

I have used gconf-editor and disabled the automount option yet I'm still seeing my iPhone after reboot:

> tim@Tim-on-Linux64:~$ `lsusb`
>   Bus 002 Device 011: ID 05ac:1297 Apple,
>   Inc.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89244/how-to-disable-automount-in-nautiluss-preferences

Answer (score 2):

So far the only way I've seen to not automount external devices is:

1. Open up the terminal and type in:

   ```
   gconf-editor
   ```
2. Scroll down to ***Nautilus -> Preferences -> Media Automount***
3. Uncheck the option for ***Media Automount***

I tested after unchecking the ***Media Automount*** option without a system restart and it did not automatically mount my iPod but it was still listed under ***Places -> iPod*** and available for mounting which equals success.

---

I then un-mounted the iPod, restarted the system, and plugged my iPod back into the system. Once again it did not automatically mount and also once again was under ***Places -> iPod*** and available to be mounted.

---

I don't know if it is just a fluke or a bug you have but using ***gconf-editor*** worked for me so I'll suggest maybe you give it another shot?

Comment: I tried your suggestion again.  No joy.  Here is there error vmware is giving me:

Comment: Uhm, you said it's giving you an error but you didn't display what that error is... Pastebin it?