# How to disable automount in nautilus's preferences

Tags: usb, automount

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 (64 bits) and I do not want to mount automatically USB thumb drives in my system. I tried the command dconf-editor and gconf-editor but there isn't the icon to disable it in nautilus preferences (apps|nautilus|preferences|media_automount).

Thanks.

Answer (score 86):

### From the command line

To disable Nautilus automount use this command in a terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
```

To enable it again open a terminal and use this command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount true
```

### From the GUI

You first need to install `dconf editor` in Software Center. In my case it shows remove because I have already installed it

[image]

Then you need to open `dconf editor` via Dash

[image]

Then goto `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling`

You will find `automount` checkbox on right hand side. Uncheck it

[image]

Comment: I have "defaced" you answer with terminal instructions just in case a user does not want to install `dconf-tools` in his system, hope that is OK with you.

Comment: @ManishSinha Where can I find the setting in Ubuntu 14.04.?

Comment: @BrunoPereira +1, good job, personally I didn't want to install a GUI tool for such simple task :)

Comment: This didn't work via ssh, I got ` dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`

Answer (score 12):

Install dconf-tools, and run dconf-editor. Then see in `dconf-editor`, key

```
org.gnome.desktop.media-handling/automount
```

Comment: If you don't already have dconf-editor installed you can find it in the Software Center.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can find `dconf-editor` is part of `dconf-tools`.  If you search for `dconf`, it should show up.

The key is under `org`. As posted, dig down to `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling/automount`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm copying [Bruno Pereira's edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/102601/2) into its own answer, since because it doesn't involve installing any additional GUI tools, it's probably the most desirable option for most people.

---

If you prefer not to install anything extra in your system. You can use `gsettings` to change dconf keys.

To disable Nautilus automount use this command in a terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
```

To enable it again open a terminal and use this command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount true
```