# Disable automount in Nautilus to avoid mount-devices being listed twice in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, mount, automount

I have added my mount devices in `/etc/fstab` and they get correctly mounted (2nd partition with `ntfs` and nas-share with `nfs`).

I have also disabled automount in Nautilus preferences by using dconf-editor (following this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89244/how-to-disable-automount-in-nautiluss-preferences)):

```
user@server:~$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.media-handling

org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount false
org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open false
org.gnome.desktop.media-handling autorun-never false
```

Now i see every mount device **twice** in Nautilus (the entry in fstab already mounted). When clicking on the other entry i get the eligible message

```
mount.nfs: /media/nas_share is busy or already mounted
```

How i can i disable the appearente of those devices in Nautilus?

**EDIT Regarding automount:**

I have only one line in `/etc/auto.master`:

```
+auto.master
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you abandon the /media... mount point and make some directories under /mnt.  Use noauto in the fstab for any /mnt entries you do not want automounted.  Seems that the noauto option is ignored when present on any /media mount point by whatever desktop software thinks it has to mount everything it sees.