# USB Flash Drive Automounting

Tags: usb-drive, automount

I'm trying to prevent my USB flashdrive from getting automounted upon insertion.

I've already set `automount` to false under `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling`, yet the flash drive continues to get mounted automatically.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I've got the same problem with 14.04. Disabled both `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling.automount` and `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling.automount-open`, and the drive is still mounted.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use "dconf" to do that:

> [How to disable automount in nautilus's preferences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89244/how-to-disable-automount-in-nautiluss-preferences)

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I already made that setting.