# how to stop ubuntu from auto mounting my phone?

Tags: mount

I am using USB cable to charge my phone, however, ubuntu auto mount my phone and show the files in it. How could I stop this?

Comment: You can prevent auto-mounting, but it's better to set up your phone not to connect card to USB when it charges. You didn't specify your phone model, so I can't give more detailed instructions.

Comment: You can see the following post [here][1].


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89244/how-to-disable-automount-in-nautiluss-preferences