# Unable to mount blank DVD-R disc. Location is already mounted error?

Tags: burning

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running in dual-boot with Linux Mint 17 (both 64bit) on a brand new Dell Inspiron N4050 i3 and I'm having a serious burning issue. Everytime I try to burn something I end up with a DVD/CD that doesn't work - no matter what tool I use (Brasero, xfburn...). This happens on both distros.

Whenever I insert a CD/DVD, I get this error:

```
"UNABLE TO MOUNT BLANK DVD-R DISC. Location is already mounted"
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: "Whenever I insert a CD/DVD" - does that mean this happens with any DVD or CD? Or do you mean the ones you burnt?

Comment: it happens with any CD/DVD and only occasionally do I succeed to burn a CD/DVD

Comment: Then this issue is not about burning - as I see it. It's about mounting.

Answer (score 4):

The question is a bit unclear about the exact nature of the problem, but I have had similar problems (including the same error message) while trying to burn .iso images to DVD-R.  And I, too, was thrown off by track by the error message.

What I thought might work, but doesn't (DVD is grayed out):

- `usb-creator-gtk` (Startup Disk Creator)
- `gnome-disks` (Disks)

What unexpectedly did work:

- `nautilus` (Files) -- Just drag the .iso to the file manager opened to the DVD.  When you click the `Write to Disc` button, it recognizes that the file is an ISO and gives you the option of burning the contents instead of the file.

What also works:

- `brasero` (Brasero Disc Burner) -- this is what nautilus launches anyway
- `cdrecord -v /dev/cdrom filename.iso`

By the way, I was able to get rid of the error message "Unable to mount Blank DVD-R Disc" "Location is already mounted" by using `dconf-editor` to disable auto-mounting as described here: [How to disable automount in nautilus's preferences](https://askubuntu.com/q/89244/11522).  However, my impression is that the message can simply be ignored.  *I would consider its presence a bug.*

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4):

It is a harmless message.  Simply close the message window and proceed with whatever you are doing.

CD/DVD writing.  I have plenty of "coasters" made by Brasero.  Xfburn works great but it won't do some things.  I added K3b to my system and it works as it does in KDE.  It adds some files which will only be used when you use K3b so they won't negatively affect your system.  K3b is the best writing software.

Comment: K3b worked for me. I wasn't able to successfully use Nautilus or brasero on Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 1):

First you should check whether the result is really blank
or whether the automounter is clueless.
(The statements "blank" and "already mounted" together
make few sense to me.)

What do the burn programs report about the medium state ?

Most original info can be expected from backend programs.

From package "dvd+rw-tools":

```
dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/sr0
```

Look for

```
Disc status:           blank
```

versus

```
Disc status:           appendable
Disc status:           complete
```

From package "xorriso".

```
xorriso -outdev /dev/sr0 -toc
```

Look for

```
Media status : is blank
```

versus

```
Media status : is written , ...
```

If the burn runs with Brasero or xfburn took a plausible time
and yielded success reports in the end, then the medium should
not be blank.
If one of above shell commands afterwards reports the medium
as blank, then the burner had no sufficient physical effect.
(I.e. demand replacement and hope for a better one.)

Comment: It actually corrupts my CDs/DVDs. It says they are blank but I can no longer use them!

Comment: Which program says that they are blank ? If it is the automounter of the desktop, then inquire by a burn program. If it is a burn program, then consider your burner drive to be bad.

Comment: "dvd+rw-mediainfo /dev/sr0" gives "READ DISC INFORMATION:
 Disc status:           complete
 Number of Sessions:    1
 State of Last Session: complete
 Number of Tracks:      1
READ TRACK INFORMATION[#1]:
 Track State:           invisible
 Track Start Address:   0*2KB
 Free Blocks:           0*2KB
 Track Size:            207488*2KB
FABRICATED TOC:
 Track#1  :             17@0
 Track#AA :             17@207488
 Multi-session Info:    #1@0
READ CAPACITY:          207488*2048=424935424"