# Which program is automounting USB drive in Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: usb, mount, 17.04, automount

I plugged in an usb and tried to mount it myself, then I realized that it was automounted at 
`/media/username/xxxx`. I was just wondering out of curiosity, which program is causing this automount? I was really looking forward to mount the usb then write to it and `umount` it but now I saw this. I wanted to do this myself.

What program is doing this and where can I change this so I can experiment?

EDIT: I want to be able to mount it myself through the terminal for learning purposes, that's why I don't want it to automount.

Comment: if you are using the default desktop, then it is Nautilus (the file manager) that is automounting.

Comment: See [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89244/how-to-disable-automount-in-nautiluss-preferences)

Comment: @ravery Is it so? I first killed Nautilus from System Monitor, then plugged in a USB flash drive. It still got automounted (appeared in `/media/USERNAME`).

Comment: see this question -- https://askubuntu.com/questions/89244/how-to-disable-automount-in-nautiluss-preferences

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable automount in nautilus's preferences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89244/how-to-disable-automount-in-nautiluss-preferences)

Comment: You could also mouse click to unmount it and continue as planned

Comment: @DavidFoerster I edited the question, if that's what you meant.

Comment: So `umount` it and mount it manually. What's the problem?