# Can I unmount media/username partition? (dual boot ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I had a PC with windows 10 installed. I put a second SSD in the PC and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. I thought I correctly selected the partition sizes but when looking at it, there are two separate main partitions.

- One is the `/` - which has only been allocated 46.56 GB.
- And a much larger `/media/[username]/[30763...]` partition with 438.63 GB.

I want everything on the `/` partition. Is it safe to unmount (delete) the `/media/` partition? Why has this `media` partition been created?

Currently the `media` partition has the standard file structure (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Public, Templates, Videos) and only contains hidden files, and none of my working files.

[image: Screenshot of partition of original SSD with windows 10]

[image: Screenshot of partition of new SSD with Ubuntu 16.04]

**EDIT**

I check again this morning and I realise that when I open the PC the `/media/[username]/[30763...]` partition with 438.63 GB doesn't initially have a name.

[image: Screenshot of partition of new SSD with Ubuntu 16.04]

However after a few minutes (maybe after opening Nautilus?), the drives are mounted and then appear again as a partition named as before (see second screenshot).

Why is this happening? I dont really want either drives to appear in my files like this:

[image]

The `499 GB Volume` is for windows and I don't want to access that from Ubuntu
And the `471 GB Volume` I would like to be part of the main `/` partition.

Also when these drives are mounted, they are both automatically locked to the task bar. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Unmounting and deleting a partition is a completely different thing.

If you unmount a partition, you just can't access it temporary. If you delete it, all of your data is gone eventually.

And according to your screenshots you /media is using 300GB. So there are more than just some hidden files.

If I know it right, under media are your mounted devices. I guess, maybe your windows partition is mounted there

EDIT:

Nautilus is probably automounting your hard drives and partitions. You can disable this as described here [How to disable automount in nautilus's preferences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89244/how-to-disable-automount-in-nautiluss-preferences) .

Or if this is not the problem, look in to your fstab file with something like

```
more /etc/fstab
```

If you see your unwanted windows partition, just comment it out with a # at the beginning of the line.

Could you please give us a feedback and maybe some more information about the 7GB used space, is there anything you need or are those really just hidden files?

Comment: Thanks BO41, I think the media folder you're looking at is the windows one (299GB used which is fine as it is - first screenshot). The media folder in the second screenshot (on my new SSD) is the one which is confusing me (and has only 7.08 GB used - second screenshot). I want this partition to be part of the main partition.