# USB Drives automount options on connect

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive, automount

I had to stuck in next problem before a week:

The 2TB USB hard drive i own was mounted automatically with async option by default (my suggestion) while causing send data to the device be cached for "faster" transaction.

As the result, longterm transaction of about 16GB of data almost ended with gigabytes data loss due to early disconnection of the drive (visual copy process end, followed by PC shutdown w/o eject).

Checking the Disks GUI shows for automatical parameters use. Switching to manual parameters use and adding "sync" mount parameter instead solved the issue.

Therefore upcoming question:
What software is actually responsible for automount on connection (mount, disks, nautilus) in case of GUI use, and how in turn to change/view the default used parameters for the operation?

The assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

as explained in the [following post](https://askubuntu.com/a/102601/650195) you can install [dconf](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf) and configure some of the default options for mounting `usb` drives.

You can disable `automount` and mount manually the drives with nautilus and you can disable `automount-open`.

Answer (score 0):

`udev` is responsible for any device events, including mounting USB drives:

> NAME
>          udev - Dynamic device management
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          udev supplies the system software with device events, manages
>          permissions of device nodes and may create additional symlinks in the
>          /dev directory, or renames network interfaces. The kernel usually just
>          assigns unpredictable device names based on the order of discovery.
>          Meaningful symlinks or network device names provide a way to reliably
>          identify devices based on their properties or current configuration.

and:

> RULES FILES
>          The udev rules are read from the files located in the system rules
>          directory /lib/udev/rules.d, the volatile runtime directory
>          /run/udev/rules.d and the local administration directory
>          /etc/udev/rules.d.

Answer (score 0):

- The one responsible for auto-mount is Gnome udisks daemon.
- To put custom options use Gnome Disks (Included) following instructions in [Is there a program to mount all of my drives automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/q/271516/26246) . Or you may used `udisks-glue`.