# Clicked on unmount instead of eject and now I can not find the DVD player

Tags: 18.04, dvd

Ubuntu 18.04. I meant to click on eject and clicked on unmount. Now I can not use the DVD player. I tried reboot and I inserted and ejected the DVD a few times. Before when I put the DVD in it wound mount and display in browser and I could access the files on it. I have a Blu Ray player on same machine and it still works like this DVD drive used to. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was user error. Wrong labeled disk. Said it was a DVD and it turns out it was a Blu Ray. There is a Blu ray drive on the computer but that was not the one I was using.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Linux command called lsblk which will list all of the connected block devices regardless of if they are mounted or not.

From there you should be able to obtain the device name and then eject/mount it.

e.g.

```
#lsblk                                
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0 55.5M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/1988
loop2         7:2    0 71.4M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/lxd/19325
loop3         7:3    0 31.1M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/10707
loop4         7:4    0 55.4M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/1944
loop5         7:5    0 31.1M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/snapd/11036
loop6         7:6    0 71.5M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/lxd/19389
sda           8:0    0   32G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2        8:2    0   31G  0 part
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0 28.8G  0 lvm  /
  └─cl-swap 253:1    0  2.2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0          11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

eject /dev/sr0
```

For adding in mount entries into /etc/fstab this link is very detailed..

https://www.cyberpratibha.com/use-of-fstab-option-for-mounting-disk-in-linux-permanent/

This one details automatic mouting of optical drives.

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-properly-automount-a-drive-in-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120160/discussion-on-answer-by-simon-banks-clicked-on-unmount-instead-of-eject-and-now).

Answer (score 2):

As your using Nautilus you can try enabling the auto mount option using the dconf command.

This guide tells you how to disable it so follow the instructions and make sure that automount is ticked..

[How to disable automount in nautilus's preferences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89244/how-to-disable-automount-in-nautiluss-preferences)

Comment: will look into it

Comment: ok i fixed the problem very embarrassing i will be deleting this question in about an hour guess what happens when you by mistake put a blue ray disk with files into the reg dvd and not the blu ray one? it does not auto mount.

Comment: It happens don't beat your self up..

Comment: I did learn a lot so that is a plus.

Comment: Thats a great attitude and Its amazing how many hours you and loose to trial issues..